# Excel: Count Weighed Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I've an excel-spreadsheet, which is my timetable. this means, that I've some tasks, which is almost always a connected cell, sometimes I connect 20 cells, sometimes only two. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYYA7.jpg)

Since every cell is one hour I wanted to count the weighed cellcount. This means: If I have a cell witch is only one cell, it counts as one, if I have 3 connected it shall count as 3. So in the example Picture, the cellcount shall be S1: 3, S2: 4, S3:2, S4:6

I've been searching a long time, but haven't found any function which does solve the problem. The best I've found, is `=countif(B4:H19, "Subject1")`, but here a cell based on three conected cells counts as one. Could you please help me solve this problem?

Thank you for your answer in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Please edit your post and add a screenshot showing some sample data. Please also add some details of a specific example referencing the sample data that shows what your desired outcome is.

Comment: What do you mean by "*connected cell*"?  If you mean a "*Merged Cell*", I'm pretty sure you'd have to write a VBA routine to detect that. If you mean something else, please clarify.

Comment: @FlexYourData Done

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, Yeah, I mean "Merged Cell".

Comment: @MelcomX  ,, check my post,, since you have both Merged as well Un-merged cells in same data range therefore any Excel formula can't count so you need is VBA Macro,,, this solve the issue ☺

Answer (score 2):

*Actually the screen shot you have shared with us has both Merged & Non-merged cells, therefore instead of any formula this issue needs VBA macro.*

[image]

---

```
   Function MergedCellCount(ByRef Rng As Range, ByVal Criteria As Variant)

    Dim c       As Long
    Dim Cell    As Range
    Dim n       As Long
    Dim r       As Long
    
        Application.Volatile
        
        For c = 1 To Rng.Columns.Count
            For r = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count
                Set Cell = Rng.Cells(r, c)
                If Cell.MergeCells = True And (Rng.Columns(c).Column = Cell.MergeArea.Column) Then
                    If Cell = Criteria Then
                        n = n + Cell.MergeArea.Count
                        r = r + (Cell.MergeArea.Rows.Count - 1)
                    End If
                End If
            Next r
        Next c
        
        MergedCellCount = n
        
    End Function
```

---

```
    Function unMergedCellCount(ByRef Rng As Range, ByVal Criteria As Variant)

    Dim c       As Long
    Dim Cell    As Range
    Dim n       As Long
    Dim r       As Long
    
        Application.Volatile
        
        For c = 1 To Rng.Columns.Count
            For r = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count
                Set Cell = Rng.Cells(r, c)
                If Cell.MergeCells <> True And (Rng.Columns(c).Column = Cell.MergeArea.Column) Then
                    If Cell = Criteria Then
                        n = n + Cell.MergeArea.Count
                        r = r + (Cell.MergeArea.Rows.Count - 1)
                    End If
                End If
            Next r
        Next c
        
        unMergedCellCount = n
        
End Function
```

---

**How it works:**

- Either press **Alt+F11** or select the TAB then **R**ight click and from the
  menu hit **V**iew code.
- **C**opy & **P**aste these VBA macro.
- Press **Alt+Q** to return to the Sheet.
- Now Save the Workbook as Macro Enabled File `*.xlsm`.
- Enter this formula in cell `K2` & fill down.

  `=MergedCellCount(H$2:H$17,J2)+unMergedCellCount(H$2:H$17,J2)`
- Adjust cell references as needed.

Comment: +1. Is it not possible to have 1 function that can count both?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio ,,, I'm trying and if it will clicked the edit the post ☺